# Java SpringMVC - converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, maven

I'm having an issue of returning a object into an JSON object, from a RESTController of a SpringMVC framework with Tomcat and maven xml, without spring boot.

Here is the exception, when requesting the URL:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class laustrup.models.Mailbox]
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class MailController {

private MailService service;

public MailController() {
    service = new MailService();
}

@RequestMapping("/hallo")
public String halloWorld() {
    return "Hallo World!";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/check_inbox", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<LinkedList<Mail>> checkInbox() {
    return service.checkInbox(); 
}

@PutMapping(value = "put_in_mail", consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Mailbox> putInMailBox(@RequestBody Mail mail) {
    return service.putMailInInbox(mail);
}

@GetMapping("take_all_mail")
public ResponseEntity<Mailbox> takeAllMail() {
    return service.takeMail();
}
}
```

Service class:

```
package laustrup.services;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import laustrup.models.Mail;
import laustrup.models.Mailbox;

@Service
public class MailService {
    
    private Mailbox mailbox;
    
    public MailService() {
        mailbox = new Mailbox("Jagtvej 67");
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<LinkedList<Mail>> checkInbox() {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        if (mailbox.inboxIsEmpty()) { 
            status = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).
                header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json").
                body(new LinkedList<Mail>());
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<Mailbox> putMailInInbox(Mail mail) {
        mailbox.addMail(mail);
        
        if (mailbox.inboxContains(mail)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Mailbox>(mailbox,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Mailbox>(new Mailbox(null),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<Mailbox> takeMail() {
        if (mailbox.emptyInbox()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Mailbox>(mailbox,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Mailbox>(new Mailbox(null),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

WEB xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-mvc.xsd"
    >

    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="laustrup.controllers"></ctx:component-scan>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="laustrup.models"></ctx:component-scan>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="laustrup.services"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

pom xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>laustrup</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mailbox</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Mailbox Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <finalName>Mailbox</finalName>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

It seems like the issue comes from a wrong dependency of jackson. Is that possible? How do I then fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention when the exception is thrown, so I assume it is on calling the endpoints.

Try adding `produces` parameter to the annotations of the 2 endpoints in the controller, that return `ResponseEntity<Mailbox>`, e.g.

`@PutMapping(value = "put_in_mail", consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")`

and

`@GetMapping("take_all_mail", produces="application/json")`

Comment: First of all thank you for the observation and sorry that the description of when the exception is thrown is a little vague. It's the other endpoints than the halloworld, hallo world works fine, when the other ones are called with a url, in my case through Postman, they have the 404 error and the exception written in the post appears on the console of Eclipse javaEE through a maven web project. According to your answer, I did previous the mapping as you have written, but changed it back and forth, since it didn't really make a difference.